# I need to add an event-log with type of Critical

Tags: c++, winapi, event-log

I want to add an event message with a **Critical** type to Windows Event Log using [`ReportEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx), but according to the documentation, only the below types are permitted:

```
EVENTLOG_SUCCESS  
EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE  
EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE  
EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE  
EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS  
EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE
```

So how do I add `EVENTLOG_CRITICAL`? As Critical messages can be seen in the Windows Event Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

As the `ReportEvent()` documentation says, it does not support "critical" messages.  There is nothing you can do or add to change that.

However, `ReportEvent()` is not the only way, or even the preferred way, to log messages to the Windows Event Log.  MSDN states the following in the documentation for the [Event Logging API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363652.aspx) (which `ReportEvent()` is part of):

> **Note** The Event Logging API was designed for applications that run on the Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, or Windows 2000 operating system. In Windows Vista, the event logging infrastructure was redesigned. Applications that are designed to run on Windows Vista or later operating systems should use [Windows Event Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780.aspx) to log events.

In the documentation for the newer [Event Log API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780.aspx), the section on [Writing an Instrumentation Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996930.aspx) has a sub-section about [Defining Severity Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996917.aspx), which shows `Win:Critical` is one of the "commonly used severity levels".

You will have to replace your existing call to `ReportEvent()` to use one of the [Event Tracing Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363795.aspx) instead ([`EventWrite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363752.aspx), [`EventWriteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd392307.aspx), [`EventWriteString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363750.aspx), [`TraceEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364137.aspx), etc).